# flush windows kernel file buffer with libc FILE pointer

Tags: windows, file, flush

I want to make sure the file go to disk before I close it, so in Linux, I can use fdatasync to do this job. But in Windows, there is no coresponding API like fdatasync. I found FlushFileBuffers some where, but this need a file Handle.

I wrote code like this and it can compile and run, but I am not sure it's really working:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(...);
fprintf(fp, ...);
flush(fp);
if (!FlushFileBuffers((HANDLE) _get_osfhandle (fp->_file)))
  {
    perror("Failed to flush file");
  }
fclose(fp);
```

Can I rely on this code?

Comment: Regardless of whether data is buffered in application buffers or by a library, the data lives in the application's address space. The next layer that the data goes through is the kernel, which keeps its own version of a write-back cache called the page cache. Dirty pages can live in the page cache for an indeterminate amount of time, depending on overall system load and I/O patterns.

Comment: Use `fflush(fp); _commit(_fileno(fp))`. [`_commit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17618685.aspx) calls `FlushFileBuffers` after taking the file lock. It sets `errno` to `EBADF` if the flush fails. You can also append `"c"` to the [`fopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) mode to have `fflush` automatically call `_commit`.

Comment: Note that in practice there is no way to guarantee that the data has really been written unless you have control over what hardware your code is running on.  It is distressingly common for disk drives to lie to the operating system about this.